# Is MATLAB HDL Coder viable for complex FPGA designs?

Tags: vhdl, matlab, hdl

I'm building a feed handler for an FPGA and, having never done this before, I'm wondering if I would be OK using MATLAB (HDL Coder) as an alternative to VHDL. Is this generally a viable options, do people ship hardware designed in MATLAB?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "viable". Take a small chunk of functionality and implement it using both approaches. Compare speed and resource usage. It didn't take me long to choose pure VHDL, but decide for yourself.

Comment: I've worked with the R2013a version of HDL Coder and at least with that version you essentially had to write your MATLAB code the same way you would write normal (V)HDL code with some additional oddities. Unless they have significantly improved it over the past 3 years I would not recommend using it for anything more than simple filter implementation.